# Calculating multiple slopes for different data sets in one frame

Tags: r

Given the following data frame (this is just a sample table as an example, so the numbers might not make a lot of sense):

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), `2005` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L), `2006` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), `2007` = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L), `2008` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L), `2009` = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L), `2010` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L), `2011` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `2012` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L), `2013` = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2014` = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 9L, 0L), `2015` = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L), `2016` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Cut Off Year` = c("2011", 
"2015", "2015", "2005", "2011", "2007")), .Names = c("ID", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "Cut Off Year"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I'm interested in is finding the slope for each row based on the years (2005-2016).

However, I want two slopes for each row. One slope for the numbers before the cut-off year (column 14) and another slope after the cut-off year.

So for example, in the first row, the cut-off year is 2011. So I want R to calculate the slope for the years 2005-2010 and write this slope in a new column ("Slope Before"), and then again calculate the slope for the years 2012-2016 and write that in a second column for the row ("Slope After").

So the end results will look something like this:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), `2005` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L), `2006` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), `2007` = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L), `2008` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L), `2009` = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L), `2010` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L), `2011` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `2012` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L), `2013` = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `2014` = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 9L, 0L), `2015` = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L), `2016` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Cut Off Year` = c("2011", 
"2015", "2015", "2005", "2011", "2007"), `Slope Before` = c("Slope1", 
"Slope2", "Slope3", "Slope4", "Slope5", "Slope6"), `Slope After` = c("Slope1", 
"Slope2", "Slope3", "Slope4", "Slope5", "Slope6")), .Names = c("ID", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "Cut Off Year", "Slope Before", "Slope After"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've tried to implement this function:

```
Slope = function(x) {
  Temporary_DF = data.frame(x, year=2:13)
  lm(x ~ year, data=Temporary_DF)$coefficients[2]
}

Transposed_Data = as.data.frame(t(DF))
DF$slope = sapply(Transposed_Data, Slope)
```

I don't think that this can be used since it doesn't take into account the cut off year, and I have no idea how to implement the cut off year. Also, I'm having an issue applying the slopes because my original data frame includes additional columns that are not parts of the slope calculations (the first and 14th column).

Comment: Please show your own attempt.

Comment: @Roland: I've edited my original post with my own attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would rearrange (tidy) your data to long format and use package data.table and its `by` (or dplyr if you prefer), but you can do this with `apply`:

```
DF[, "Cut Off Year"] <- as.numeric(DF[, "Cut Off Year"])

Slope = function(x) {
  Temporary_DF = data.frame(y = x, year=seq_along(x))
  lm(y ~ year, data=Temporary_DF)$coefficients[2]
}

years <- 2005:2016

DF[, c("Slope Before", "Slope After")] <- t(apply(DF[, c(years, "Cut Off Year")], 1,
      function(x) {
        y <- x[-length(x)]
        #subset:
        a <- y[years < x[length(x)]]
        b <- y[years > x[length(x)]]
        a <- if (length(a) > 1) Slope(a) else NA_real_
        b <- if (length(b) > 1) Slope(b) else NA_real_
        c(a, b)
      }))

#  ID 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 Cut Off Year Slope Before   Slope After
#1  1    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0         2011   0.08571429 -1.000000e-01
#2  2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         2015   0.00000000            NA
#3  3    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    2    1    0         2015   0.12121212            NA
#4  4    2    1    0    4    2    5    0    4    0    0    0    0         2005           NA -2.000000e-01
#5  5    1    1    3    3    3    0    1    1    0    9    2    0         2011   0.02857143  2.106500e-16
#6  6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0         2007   0.00000000  1.791615e-18
```

Note the floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, when I run the last part of the code `DF[, c("Slope Before", "Slope After")] <-...` I get the following error that I've never seen before: `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases`

Comment: Does your data contain `NA`, `NaN` or `Inf` values?

Comment: Yes it does. But removing those NA values made the code run. Thank you!

Comment: You could change the `if` conditions to `if (length(na.omit(a)) > 1)`.